# Serverkey Exchange in C++ Openssl

Tags: c++, ssl, encryption, openssl

I'm using openssl in a c++ project. Through my code handshaking done without Serverkey Exchange and I need to do this. How can I add serverkey exchange in handshaking to my code?

server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


/* define HOME to be dir for key and cert files... */
#define HOME "./"
/* Make these what you want for cert & key files */
#define CERTF  "/home/a.seifpour/Desktop/SSL Tutorial/cert.pem"
#define KEYF  "/home/a.seifpour/Desktop/SSL Tutorial/key.pem"


#define CHK_NULL(x) if ((x)==NULL) exit (1)
#define CHK_ERR(err,s) if ((err)==-1) { perror(s); exit(1); }
#define CHK_SSL(err) if ((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);     exit(2); }

int main() {
    int err;
    int listen_sd;
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in sa_serv;
    struct sockaddr_in sa_cli;
    unsigned int client_len;
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    SSL* ssl;
    X509* client_cert;
    char* str;
    char buf [4096];
    const SSL_METHOD *meth;

    /* SSL preliminaries. We keep the certificate and key with the     context. */

    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
    meth = TLSv1_2_server_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
    if (!ctx) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(2);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CERTF, KEYF) != 1){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx) != 1){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CERTF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <=     0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(3);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEYF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)     {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(4);
    }

    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the certificate     public key\n");
        exit(5);
    }

//    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, 0);

    /* ----------------------------------------------- */
    /* Prepare TCP socket for receiving connections */

    listen_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    CHK_ERR(listen_sd, "socket");

    memset(&sa_serv, 0, sizeof (sa_serv));
    sa_serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa_serv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sa_serv.sin_port = htons(9999); /* Server Port number */

    err = bind(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa_serv,
            sizeof (sa_serv));
    CHK_ERR(err, "bind");

    /* Receive a TCP connection. */

    err = listen(listen_sd, 5);
    CHK_ERR(err, "listen");

    client_len = sizeof (sa_cli);
    sd = accept(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa_cli, &client_len);
    CHK_ERR(sd, "accept");
    close(listen_sd);

    printf("Connection from %lx, port %x\n",
            sa_cli.sin_addr.s_addr, sa_cli.sin_port);

    /* ----------------------------------------------- */
    /* TCP connection is ready. Do server side SSL. */

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    CHK_NULL(ssl);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sd);    

    err = SSL_accept(ssl);
    CHK_SSL(err);

    /* Get the cipher - opt */

    printf("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));

    /* Get client's certificate (note: beware of dynamic allocation) -     opt */

    client_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    if (client_cert != NULL) {
        printf("Client certificate:\n");

        str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(client_cert), 0,     0);
        CHK_NULL(str);
        printf("\t subject: %s\n", str);
        OPENSSL_free(str);

        str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(client_cert), 0,     0);
        CHK_NULL(str);
        printf("\t issuer: %s\n", str);
        OPENSSL_free(str);

        /* We could do all sorts of certificate verification stuff     here before
           deallocating the certificate. */

        X509_free(client_cert);
    } else
        printf("Client does not have certificate.\n");

    /* DATA EXCHANGE - Receive message and send reply. */

    err = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof (buf) - 1);
    CHK_SSL(err);
    buf[err] = '\0';
    printf("Got %d chars:'%s'\n", err, buf);

    err = SSL_write(ssl, "I hear you.", strlen("I hear you."));
    CHK_SSL(err);

    /* Clean up. */

    close(sd);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}
/* EOF - serv.cpp */
```

client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

/* define HOME to be dir for key and cert files... */
#define HOME "./"
/* Make these what you want for cert & key files */
#define CERTF  "/home/a.seifpour/Desktop/SSL Tutorial/cert.pem"
#define KEYF  "/home/a.seifpour/Desktop/SSL Tutorial/key.pem"

#define CHK_NULL(x) if ((x)==NULL) exit (1)
#define CHK_ERR(err,s) if ((err)==-1) { perror(s); exit(1); }
#define CHK_SSL(err) if ((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);     exit(2); }

int main() {
    int err;
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    SSL* ssl;
    X509* server_cert;
    char* str;
    char buf [4096];
    const SSL_METHOD *meth;

    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
    meth = TLSv1_2_client_method();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
    CHK_NULL(ctx);

//    if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-    SHA384") != 1)
//        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

    /* ----------------------------------------------- */
    /* Create a socket and connect to server using normal socket     calls. */

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    CHK_ERR(sd, "socket");

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); /* Server IP */
    sa.sin_port = htons(9999); /* Server Port number */

    err = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa, sizeof (sa));
    CHK_ERR(err, "connect");

    /* ----------------------------------------------- */
    /* Now we have TCP conncetion. Start SSL negotiation. */

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    CHK_NULL(ssl);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sd);
    err = SSL_connect(ssl);
    CHK_SSL(err);

    /* Following two steps are optional and not required for
       data exchange to be successful. */

    /* Get the cipher - opt */

    printf("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));

    /* Get server's certificate (note: beware of dynamic allocation) -     opt */


    server_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    CHK_NULL(server_cert);
    printf("Server certificate:\n");

    str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(server_cert), 0, 0);
    CHK_NULL(str);
    printf("\t subject: %s\n", str);
    OPENSSL_free(str);

    str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(server_cert), 0, 0);
    CHK_NULL(str);
    printf("\t issuer: %s\n", str);
    OPENSSL_free(str);

    /* We could do all sorts of certificate verification stuff here     before
       deallocating the certificate. */

    X509_free(server_cert);

    /* --------------------------------------------------- */
    /* DATA EXCHANGE - Send a message and receive a reply. */

    err = SSL_write(ssl, "Hello World!", strlen("Hello World!"));
    CHK_SSL(err);

    err = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof (buf) - 1);
    //    err = recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    CHK_SSL(err);
    buf[err] = '\0';
    printf("Got %d chars:'%s'\n", err, buf);
    SSL_shutdown(ssl); /* send SSL/TLS close_notify */

    /* Clean up. */

    //    close(sd);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}
/* EOF - cli.cpp */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServerKeyExchange` is a message that is send for the ephemeral Diffie-Hellman protocols. You don't need to change your code for that, you just need to enable (only?) the DHE and ECDHE cipher suites. It seems that your cipher suite selection is outside the code you provided.

Before you switch on these ciphersuites, please make sure you know about the attacks on these protocols, e.g. Logjam and at least only allow secure key sizes.